# Can I hide individual elements from Store product details field

Tags: expresso-store

I'd like to hide certain unused fields from the store product details field on the publish page. Is this possible?

Have a product channel with a store product details tag and like to hide the "min. order quantity" field as it is irrelevant in this particular situation and it only confuses the user.

Comment: Are you talking about the control panel, or in a Safecracker form? Either way, your only option would be to add some javascript or CSS to hide the fields you don't need.

Comment: I'm talking about the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in way to customize the look of the Store product details field in the control panel entry screen.

One option you have if you need to do this is create an extension which uses the `cp_css_end` hook to add your own CSS to the control panel, which hides the fields you don't need.

Comment: Adrian, has this changed since Jan'13? I am building a site with download ONLY products - width/length/height/weight and even handling surcharge & the free shipping checkbox are all irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the channel:entries tag you can write conditionals based on the [**{channel_id}**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-id) or [**{channel_short_name}**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-short-name). For example:

```
{if channel_id != "10"}SHOW "min. order quantity" field{/if}
```

or

```
{if channel_short_name != "big_products" OR channel_short_name != "small_products"}SHOW "min. order quantity" field{/if}
```