# Store: Hide modifiers section by default?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, fields

Just a very minor question but is there a way to have the modifiers panel contracted by default? Shipping an advanced panels both seem to be hidden by default and I'd like to do the same to modifiers to make things as clutter free and simple to use from a system administrator's point of view (they seem to get overwhelmed when they see so many open fields all at once when they only need price and SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the look of the Store product details field, without adding your own CSS to the control panel (or editing the Store view files).

One option you have if you need to do this is create an extension which uses the `cp_css_end` hook to add your own CSS to the control panel, which hides the fields you don't need.

Reference: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5205/150

Comment: OK, thanks Adrian. In addition it seems that Brandon Kelly already has a [useful addon](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) available to modify CP CSS and JS. This takes an extra step out of the equation and should provide a way to close the unused drawers.

Comment: Ah very nice. You can also apparently add CSS and JS directly into the "field instructions" box when configuring your channel fields, and it will be displayed on the entry page, though this is more of an XSS bug EllisLab should fix so I'm not sure I would want to rely on it.